# how to set spinner item position

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I am creating an android app in which I want to add values in spinner i.e countries. I added them successfully, but I want to show my desire country at the top of the spinner list i.e I want to show Australia at the 0 index of the spinner. So how I can achieve this? Anyone please help me.

Here is my code:

```
    MySpinnerAdapter adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(SignUp.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryname);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_country.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner_country.setSelection(countryname.size() - 1);
    spinner_country.setSelection(12);

    Collections.sort(countryname);
```

Now I am doing this and it shows `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
    String[] str = new String[countryname.size()-1];
    str = countryname.toArray(str);

    int indexTarget = 13;
    String valueAtIndex = str[indexTarget];
    for(int i = indexTarget; i > 0; i--){
        str[i] = str[i-1];
    }
    str[0] = valueAtIndex;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
    MySpinnerAdapter adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(SignUp.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_country.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner_country.setSelection(countryname.size() - 1);
    Collections.sort(countryname);
```

Comment: setSelection is show given index value to spinner but if you wan to show spinner list item as per your requirement then you have arrange your list before given to spinner.

Comment: Why don't you start adding the names to your array with `Australia`?

Comment: @ hareshsetselection shows Australia as selected but i want to show Australia at index 0 of spinner list

Comment: you can set australia at 1st position by setting it in your arraylist at 1st position using countryname.add(1,"Australia");Also note that add method DOES NOT overwrites the element previously
at the specified index in the list. It shifts the elements to right side and increasing the list size by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Australia to be at the first position in spinner then add it to zeroth index of your `countryname`.

You can start adding names to your `countryname` with `Australia` so that it will be at zeroth index and appear at first position in spinner.

`spinner.setSelection(12)` will select the 13th value from the array you are supplying to your adapter. It will not be at the first position.

**EDIT**

This is just an example, you need to modify accordingly. Here the original array is `B, M, T, A, C`, I want `A` to be first, so I need `index of A`. For your question you need the index of `Australia`

```
    String[] str = {"B", "M", "T", "A", "C"};;
    int indexTarget = 3;
    String valueAtIndex = str[indexTarget];
    for(int i = indexTarget; i > 0; i--){
       str[i] = str[i-1];
    }
    str[0] = valueAtIndex;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        System.out.println(str[i]);
```

**Output**

A
B
M
T
C

Now `A` is at first position.

Comment: Thanks its solved my problem but how i can assign str[i] to spinner?

Comment: Don't assign str[i], just pass `str` to your adapter. You should write this code before passing the `String array` to `Adapter`. Then rest of your code remains same.

Comment: i am doing this  List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
            MySpinnerAdapter adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(SignUp.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringList);  its giving error of Arrayindexoutofbound

Comment: What is `countryname`?

Comment: countyname is Arraylist

Comment: Then just do this `countryname.add(0, "Australia");`

Comment: countryname.add(0, "Australia") in this case Australia come 2 times in the list

Comment: ok, use `countryname.remove(pos)`. pos is index of other Australia. Why don't you google and go through java concepts once? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: will you please ans my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202739/how-to-set-interval-in-timer-picker-dialog